# What determines the SignalR connectionID and how to set it manually

Tags: c#, connection, signalr

I'm playing around with SignalR and was wandering how SignalR creates a connectionID is this based on my IP adress, the device I connect with or something else? And wether it is possible to set this ID manually. Let say I have a database with users which I give a unique number, can I use that number for the connectionID?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SignalR connection Id is a generated guid. If you'd like to target users in a more meaningful way with your data, I found it useful to **pass something** with your client connection, such as a user Id and some other data from your database, along to the signalr hub and craft up a group based on what you provide. It should be a 1:1 mapping if you're trying to isolate users with your own identifiers.

you can do this by overriding `OnConnected()` in your hub, and implementing something like this, which would map the generated Id to your own. You can then target these groups (remember, 1:1, emulating an Id selector) to your liking.

---

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var user = new User()
    {
        Id = Context.QueryString["Id"]
        Name = Context.QueryString["Name"]
    }

    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, user.Id);

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

---

[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)  goes into more detail as well.